# How and When to Use Marginalization in Stan

Tags: latent-variable, marginal-distribution, stan

From looking at the Stan documentation and user forums, marginalization is a technique where you sum over some parameters and that allows you to exclude them from the likelihood function.

In particular, the documentation says it can be much faster to marginalize out some discrete parameters in finite mixtures and latent discrete parameter models (the examples of the latter were beyond me in the documentation).

Nevertheless, I still don't really understand when and how to use it in my own models.

One question in particular is whether it would it make sense to use the technique with continuous latent variables in Stan?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stan only samples from continuous parameter spaces, so for something like a finite mixture model, it is necessary to do marginalization to use Stan. On the other hand, if you have a hierarchical model where a small number of parameters control the distribution of a large number of parameters, marginalization is probably not necessary.

Since marginalization, whether over discrete or continuous latent variables, reduces the dimension of the parameter space, one could expect that you would get a speed up in sampling. However, if you don't draw samples from the full posterior distribution, then that limits what you can do inference on. Also, the integration is usually not trivial, so there is an associated cost. Whether it would make sense for you depends on your problem and objective.